# Linking Django and nginx containers when deploying

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I've made an app that uses two containers.  When I use docker-compose to build the images and run the containers, everything works fine, and I can access my app in the browser over the localhost.

I then rename/tag the images and upload them to dockerhub.

I have written a second docker-compose.yml that pulls these two images from dockerhub, makes a network, and runs them.  They both appear to load properly, but when I direct my browser to localhost, I only get the 'Welcome to Ngninx - further configuration required' screen.

I have used 'docker network inspect' to compare the two networks, and all seems to be the same, bar very minor ip address changes.

```
CHESS_NN_WEBAPP
│   docker-compose.yml
│   docker-compose_deploy.yml
│   Dockerfile
│   requirements.txt
│
├───config
│   └───nginx
│       └───conf.d
│               local.conf
│
├───django_wrapper
│   │   db.sqlite3
│   │   manage.py
│   │
│   ├───django_wrapper
│   │       asgi.py
│   │       settings.py
│   │       urls.py
│   │       wsgi.py
│   │
│   └───webapp
│       │   admin.py
│       │   apps.py
│       │   chess_tools.py
│       │   urls.py
│       │   views.py
│       │
│       ├───templates
│               index.html
│ 
└───other stuff
```

Dockerfile for django/gunicorn app container:

```
# start from official image
FROM python:3.10-slim

# arbitrary location choice: you can change the directory
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/djangoapp/src
WORKDIR /opt/services/djangoapp/src

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /opt/services/djangoapp/src/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install opencv-python-headless

# copy project code
COPY . /opt/services/djangoapp/src
# start django server
RUN cd django_wrapper && python manage.py 

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# define default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "django_wrapper", "--bind", ":80", 
        "django_wrapper.wsgi:application", "--timeout", "0"]
```

docker-compose.yml that builds the images:

```
version: '3'

services:
  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: pagespeed/nginx-pagespeed:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Nginx conf.d:

```
# first we declare our upstream server, which is our Gunicorn application
upstream chess_nn {
    server djangoapp:80;
}

# now we declare our main server
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # everything is passed to Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://chess_nn;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

So far, everything works as it should (ie. I have access over localhost), so the two resulting images are tagged as 'colurw/chess_nn:webapp' and 'colurw/chess_nn:nginx' and pushed to Docker Hub.

My docker-compose.yml file for pulling and running these images is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  djangoapp:
    image: colurw/chess_nn:webapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  nginx:
    image: colurw/chess_nn:nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Running docker-compose up with this file results in both containers working... I can see the nginx screen in my browser, and gunicorn log says "Listening at: [http://0.0.0.0:80"](http://0.0.0.0:80%22), but I can also see from the log that a browser request doesn't make it that far, as the normal response (which includes loading chess_tools.py the first time localhost is accessed) doesn't happen.

This is the results of "docker network investigate" on the non-working containers' network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "chess_nn_webapp_nginx_network",
        "Id": "40ece5962610e64d605b579ee27bf71b3e665767bc67af3d0767a1e58a27adff",
        "Created": "2024-02-01T15:57:41.422912742Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2b89f8fbe62acc31d08420cb97fb7fc264743b2efb3715856d78e3b13ffe5265": {
                "Name": "chess_nn_webapp-djangoapp-1",
                "EndpointID": "20abea988881a827caa1671e3ffb38cc35983b52961fde9674781c1bdc56a1d1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b3669a895bd52023c949505b7174f4e1d0a6570dbfa955af22f0fc5f5789afc3": {
                "Name": "chess_nn_webapp-nginx-1",
                "EndpointID": "2e156010866564e4261befda0d6980b7aea2c12bc0077a6ea5e4bb4c854f80e0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "nginx_network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "chess_nn_webapp",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.23.3"
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks for making it this far!  Please, if you have any suggestions of what the problem is here, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Nginx container, in your local environment, you are injecting a local Nginx configuration file at run time

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

but in the remote deployment this configuration is missing.

Your remote deployment already is written to expect a custom image for the Nginx proxy, so the easiest change might be to include the configuration file in the image.  This can be a very simple Dockerfile

```bash
# Dockerfile.nginx
FROM pagespeed/nginx-pagespeed:latest
COPY config/nginx/conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

and your Compose file needs to be told to build the image, and not mount a volume

```yaml
  nginx:
    image: colurw/chess_nn:nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    # volumes:   <-- delete
    #   - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
    networks:   # consider deleting as well
      - nginx_network
```

In the local environment, I'd similarly consider deleting the `volumes:` for the `djangoapp` container.  This has the effect of replacing all of the image's code with content from your host system, which means that locally you're not actually running the image you're deploying.  It's also safe to delete all of the `networks:` blocks from the entire file, since Compose will create a network named `default` and automatically attach all of the containers to it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that David, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Cheers... It works.  Many Thanks. (I also added of RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf) to clear out the old config file.